# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument when running New-AzureQuickVM

Tags: powershell, azure

I've the following PowerShell script:

```
 Param(  
       $AccountName = "AccountName",
       $Guid = "Get-Random",
       $ImageName = "ImageName",
       $vmName = "VM-$Guid",
       $ServiceName = "ServiceName",
       $adminLogin = "adminLogin",
       $adminPasswd = "adminPasswd!",
       $location = "South Central US",
       $instanceSize = "Medium",
       $subscriptionDataFile = "file.publishsettings"
        )
    ########################Import Azure Public Setting And Assign Storage###########################
    Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile $subscriptionDataFile 
    Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $AccountName -CurrentStorageAccountName scrprod -PassThru

    #########################Create A VM From Existing Image And Remove It##########################


    for($i=1; $i -le 5; $i++)
    {
    New-AzureQuickVM –Windows –Location $location –ServiceName $ServiceName `
     –Name $vmName –InstanceSize $InstanceSize –ImageName $ImageName–AdminUsername $adminLogin –Password $adminPasswd -WaitForBoot 
    })
```

and I get the following exception:
New-AzureQuickVM : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'â€Windows â€Location'.

What am I doing wrong?

Second I'd like to create 5 VM's with a unique name - Is that the correct way to do it?

Thanks,

Oren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the encoding of your text file is incorrect, or you are using the incorrect characters (perhaps from a cut and paste).

Your code

```
New-AzureQuickVM –Windows –Location
```

Is somehow being evaluated as

```
New-AzureQuickVM 'â€Windows â€Location'
```

I suggest deleting the `-` characters before `Windows` and `Location` (and elsewhere likely) and then re-typing it. Also check your file's encoding and character set.

Comment: good shout, I had this issue recently when I copied syntax to one of my scripts from the ISE to outlook when emailing a script and usage instructions to someone, outlook mangled it!

Comment: Yeah. outlook changed the encoding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have formatting errors in the call of the New-AzureQuickVM cmdlet, most notably the backtick after `$ServiceName` could cause issues if not immediately followed by a new line. Also, there should be a space between `$ImageName` and `-AdminUsername`.

I terms of the guid, I would create one using `$guid = ([guid]::NewGuid()).ToString()` but really the definition of random is up to you.